# How to test multiple different type return value in unit test?

Tags: matlab, unit-testing

My code and test code are as follows:

return two value, one is vector, and is boolean. Using command to test is ok. But in unit test it is in error.

command test as follows:

```
nLine = 1./[10,100000; 100000,10; -10,1000000; 100000,-10]';
mm = [0,0];
[nPoint,isConverge] = get_line_intersect(nLine,mm)
```

unit test call return error

```
---------
Error ID:
---------
'MATLAB:catenate:dimensionMismatch'
--------------
Error Details:
--------------
Error using horzcat
Dimensions of arrays being concatenated are not consistent.

Error in get_line_intersectTest>testRect (line 13)
expSolution = [nPointData,true];
```

my code:

```
function [nPoint,isConverge] = get_line_intersect(nLine,mm)
switch length(nLine)
    case 4
        L1 = nLine(:,1);
        L2 = nLine(:,2);
        L3 = nLine(:,3);
        L4 = nLine(:,4);
        x12=[L1';L2']\ones(2,1)+mm';
        x23=[L2';L3']\ones(2,1)+mm';
        x34=[L3';L4']\ones(2,1)+mm';
        x41=[L4';L1']\ones(2,1)+mm';
        nPoint = round([x12 x23 x34 x41]),
        isConverge = ~any(nPoint(:)> 10^4);
    case 3
        L1 = nLine(:,1);
        L2 = nLine(:,2);
        L3 = nLine(:,3);
        x12=[L1';L2']\ones(2,1)+mm';
        x23=[L2';L3']\ones(2,1)+mm';
        x31=[L3';L1']\ones(2,1)+mm';
        nPoint = round([x12 x23 x31]);
        isConverge = ~any(nPoint(:)> 10^4);
end
end
```

test code

```
function tests = get_line_intersectTest
tests = functiontests(localfunctions);
end

%% 4 line test
function testRect(testCase)
nLine = 1./[10,100000; 100000,10; -10,1000000; 100000,-10]';
mm = [0,0];
actSolution = get_line_intersect(nLine,mm);
nPointData = ...%[10,10;-10,10;-10,-10;10,-10]';
    [10   -10   -10    10;...
    10    10   -10   -10];
expSolution = [nPointData,true];
verifyEqual(testCase,actSolution,expSolution)
end
```

Comment: The error I am getting is here: `expSolution = [nPointData,true];`. Here `nPointData` is 2 x 4 and `true` is 1x1. These of course cannot be concatenated. What exactly did you mean to do? What is the function of `verifyEqual`? If you just want to join these together, consider using a cell array `expSolution = {nPointData,true};`.

Comment: Thank you for your remind. Unit test code has error, I haven't written it before. solved.